# gvim colorscheme looks different when I open it with sudo

Tags: vim

Ok this is a weird problem. I am using gvim and I wanted to edit the gvimrc so I opened with  
sudo gvim gvimrc and it looks nice but when I open it normally by typing only gvim it looks different.

This is how it looks when I start with sudo:

[image]

This is how it looks when I start it normally:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `/usr/share/vim/` is where Vim's *system-wide* runtime files are stored. That directory is off-limits: you have no business adding, changing, or removing *anything* in there.

1. Copy `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc` to its normal location:

   ```
   $ sudo cp /usr/share/vim/gvimrc ~/.gvimrc
   ```
2. Remove everything you have added manually to `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc` in order to revert to its pristine state.
3. Remove everything from `~/.gvimrc` that you didn't put yourself back when the file was in `/usr/share/vim/`.

Once you are done, you should have the exact opposite of what you currently have:

- a "nice looking" normal `gvim`,
- and a "not so nice looking" `sudo gvim`, which should be useless anyway.

Comment: hey very thanks for your reply i got it working